# mpu6050&dmp and stm32h7 usage

Tags: stm32, euler-angles, mpu6050, imu, dmp

I trying to use mpu6050 with dmp but how I can do that? I didn't find any source, any register or something like that. I have a stm32h7 right now but there is no library related to this or I didn't find again. please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

MPU6050's DMP has to be programmed first by the main micro-controller. The code is in form of HEX and it is to be uploaded when the program starts.

This is done by the Invensense Motion Driver.You would likely have to download the motion driver from [Invensense website](https://invensense.tdk.com), define device specific i2c functions and then use the DMP functionality.

If you are planning to use Mbed Abstraction layer, you may find [this library](https://github.com/vmanoj1996/DMP-MPU9250-PlatformIO-library) helpful too,